# Suppress messages printing from a const method

Tags: c++, methods, constants

I have a class with a method that performs some checks on some variables and returns a value and, eventually, prints a warning message. As the method doesn't change any class variable, I've defined it as const. However to avoid to flood the output I would like to suppress the warning printing after few (or just one) prints. I've not been able to find a solution keeping the method const, is that possible (easy)?

Comment: You can define local counter in your function as static variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about use `mutable` counter? I think, it should be acceptable, since it's not state of object, it's internal logic state.

Something like this

```
class Printer
{
public:
   Printer() : counter(0) {}
   void output() const
   {
      if (counter++ < max_warnings)
      {
         std::cout << "Something special" << std::endl;
      }
   }
private:
   static const size_t max_warnings = 5;
   mutable size_t counter;
};
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/9RkYA2)

Since there are many comments about multithreading, example with atomic counter

```
class Printer
{
public:
   Printer() : counter(0) {}
   void output() const
   {
      if (counter++ < max_warnings)
      {
         std::cout << "Something special" << std::endl;
      }
   }
private:
   static const size_t max_warnings = 5;
   mutable std::atomic<size_t> counter;
};
```

Comment: +1 But you should make sure that you don't run into problems with multi-threading. If a method is marked `const`, users usually expect it to be MT-safe, so you might want to consider using an atomic counter instead.

Comment: @DanielFrey you are right, but I think, that it is excess for this example.

Comment: @DanielFrey for an error suppressor I could admit a small race condition, but of course in more delicate situations one should add also atomicity.

Comment: And FWIW, those "users" include the standard libraries. So if this function were some operation used by a container or an algorithm (or if it's called from any such `const` operation) then it *must* be thread-safe in C++11. However, IIRC the wording in the standard doesn't explicitly spell this out, rather it says that the library's `const` operations are thread-safe. This guarantee fails if the objects the library acts on from its `const` operations aren't. Herb Sutter is very excited about this area, IIRC his view is that the standard should just require `const` to mean "thread-safe" always.

Comment: Oh, and "admitting a small race condition" is in principle always risky, since a program with a data race has undefined behavior. There's no restriction in the standard on how badly it can go wrong, although you might guess (based on what you know of your compiler and architecture) that it will either print the message or not without any unpleasant side-effects. I should also clarify, that the kind of thread-safety I'm talking about here is that concurrent/unsequenced read ops do not cause a data race -- it's OK if mixing reads with writes (that is, `const` ops with non-`const`) is unsafe.

Comment: While in prsctice there are few platforms on which unordered `++` cause you to format the hard drive, you might want to check `< max_warnings` instead of `!=` to be a touch defensive about it.

Answer (score 0):

You may (sticking to the *counter* example from ForEveR)

- cast `const` away via `const_cast<int>(counter)`
- use a variable as counter that isn't in this object

The solution will depend on you actual problem, would you add a code snippet to the question?

Comment: I would avoid a const_cast by design and the counter should stay in the object as any instance should have its specific counter. I think mutable fits very well this case. For a code snippet please refer to ForEveR's answer, he's got exactly the point.

Comment: @DarioP: I see, that's why I asked for a code snippet :) but the question title leaves this open, so my suggestion could be an option to others. And the word _suppress messages_ seemed to me like you are fighting against a compiler warning...

Comment: ...so I made an edit to your question, which might be unapproved yet.

Comment: ...which was [rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3264075) ;) maybe you wish to clarify a bit...